# Running a thread for some fixed time and killing it if time is out

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, thread-safety, timeout

I want to run a thread for some fixed amount of time.
 If it is not completed within that time, I want to either kill it, throw some exception, or handle it in some way. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

You should use an [`ExecutorService`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html):

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<Integer> future = executor.submit(new Task());

try {
    System.out.println("Started");
    Integer retval = future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)); // you can choose your desired time here
    System.out.println("Finished");
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
   future.cancel(true);
   System.out.println("Timeout happened");
   // handle termination here
}

executor.shutdownNow();
```

And your `Callable` can look something like this:

```
class Task implements Callable<Integer> {
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        // some code here
        return 0;
    }
}
```